# ¿problema para usar android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Cordial saludo, no se como formular la pregunta pero si describo el problema tal vez alguien pueda ayudarme, resulta y pasa que corro el android studio y cuando escribo el codigo por mas correcto que lo haga me muestra errores en cada palabra, usando la opcion Show context action me quita el error y me muestra otros errores, tambien ignora los comandos como Ctrl + C o Ctrl + V y mas bien se pone el cursor en sobreescribir, si le doy clic derecho y copiar/pegar aveces lo ignora y en su lugar me muestra un mensaje que dice. key promoter command Ctrl + c 1 times missed, soy novato en android studio, pero puedo hacer un ejercicio al pie de la letra incluso los de google, aunque sea paso por paso igual me muestra los errores y en ocaciones de tanto usar el show context action no solo se modifica el ejercisio completamente, sino que ademas no se quitan los errores[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: Quizá si Gradle se sincronizara correctamente desaparecerían algunos de los problemas. Y key promoter parece ser una extensión.

Comment: Agrega el contenido de tus archivos build.gradle